# Matlab approximate equality x*ln(x) = 3

Tags: matlab

Function 'solve' works fine with polynomials but when I input

```
syms x
solve ('x*ln(x)=3', x)
```

I get 3/lambertw (0,3)

I know I can work backwards but variable x appears 4 times in an equation, making it rather inconvenient. 
Thanks for help

Comment: Your answer is right there in front of you: x = 3/lambertw(0,3). What is your question?

Comment: Well then, how do I compute lambertw(0,3)??

Comment: simply type lambertw(0,3) in MATLAB. I think lambert is a series so you can just calculate numeric value for it.

Comment: It appears to be working. Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Answer (score 2):

If you want a numeric solution, there is no need to go the symbolic route first:

You can simply solve the equation `x*ln(x)-3=0` using `fzero` (starting far away enough from zero to avoid logs of negative numbers):

```
x = fzero(@(x)x*log(x)-3, 10)
```